# Insert values from an array into MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Assuming I have an array as follows:

```
$array = array('first_value', 
               'second_value', 
               'thrid_value', 'and so on');
```

And a Column in which I'd want to insert those values, but each value in a separate row.

Would it it be possible to do that?

Obviously there are some answers to this one would be just loop thru the array elements and for every loop execute an insert statement, but that just seems unwise.

Or given that I'd have an ID column, that would help a lot(but I don't).

The amount of data to be introduced is not terribly large so the loop is perfectly viable, I just wanna make sure there isn't some easier way to do this that I may not be aware of.

Comment: I would definitely say looping is the easiest way to go here.

Comment: MySQL supports multi-value insertion using INSERT INTO ... VALUES ... (...) where each (...) is a set of values, separated by a "," it is a new set

Answer (score 1):

You could use prepared statements; the first query will send the SQL statement and the subsequent calls will only send the data, thereby reducing the load:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO mytable (colname) VALUES (?)');

foreach ($array as $value) {
    $stmt->execute(array($value));
}
```

If you're using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), such as the above example, make sure to disable prepared statement emulation.

Answer (score 0):

```
// connect to database and store the resource in $connection
$array = array('first_value', 
               'second_value', 
               'thrid_value', 'and so on');

foreach($array as $value)
{
 $value=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$value);
 mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO yourTABLE(columnName) VALUES('$value')");
}
```

Comment: You can make it into one, by adding after the ('$value') another one with a "," before it

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much what I'm gonna do. Don't see any other way out of it :(

Comment: @nrathaus that's correct, just didn't want to confuse them, I'm sure many such answers will also come up shortly.

Comment: It is not efficient if you have hundreds / thousands of values

Comment: Lol, why are you getting angry on me and downvoting my correct answer when I didn't downvote your incorrect answer? I was nice enough to fix your syntax error too :). Your downvote is not from me, but mine is from you which is funny. haha

Comment: who is getting angry - not me? I downvote as in my opinion it's not efficient so it is not the best way to do it. Thanks for correcting my spelling error :)

Comment: According to SO's terms, you only down vote an answer `if it is not useful`. If the answer is correct then it being the best or second best does not warrant a down vote. However I don't have time to waste on such things. Go fix your syntax error first then tell others how bad their answers are. Your syntax error was added back by you and it is still there.

Comment: nice aproach :) BTW, I'm not complaining if someone downvote my answer - can not see any problem here...

Answer (score 0):

You can put them all into a single `INSERT` statement with multiple `VALUES` lists.

```
$values = implode(',', array_map(function($v) use ($mysqli) {
    return "'" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($v) . "'"; },
  $array));
$query = "INSERT INTO yourTable (Column) VALUES $values";
$mysqli->execute($query) or die ($mysqli->error);
```

Answer (score 0):

From [mysql manual for insert](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html),you may try this:

`INSERT INTO yourtable (column_name) VALUES (value_a), (value_b), (value_c);`

Answer (score -1):

```
$array = array('first_value','second_value','third_value');

$SQL = "INSERT INTO `table` (column) VALUES('".implode("'),('",$array)."')";
```

OR

```
$values = '';
foreach($array as $val){
$values .= !empty($values)? ",('{$val}')" : "('{$val}')"; 
}

$SQL = "INSERT INTO `table` (column) VALUES{$values}";
```

Comment: `And a Column ` means only one column

Comment: Yes, he says one column, you are doing it to all three

Comment: Not gonna work like that buddy, all the values have to go into a single column.

Comment: So what's the problem - iterate on the array and insert value. Or in one query - script updated. It will be more efficient rather than do n inserts!